# Why modern mathematics prefer $\sigma$-algebra to $\sigma$-ring in measure theory?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Actually, i posted the exact same question before (about a year ago), but now i lost my past account so i couldn't find the past post..

So i googled this, but i couldn't find a satisfying post.

I'll illustrate two different situations below

========

First definition

> Let $X$ be a set and $\sum \subset P(X)$.
>   Then, $\sum$ is a sigma algebra *on* $X$ iff (1)it is closed under countable union, (2)it is closed under complement and (3)$X\in \sum$

If we start measure theory via this definition, just like topology, for a given sigma algebra, we can immediately know that on which set this sigma algebra is defined.

Thus, this definition makes it possible to view a sigma-algebra as a measurable space.

=======

Second definition

> Let $X$ be a set and $\sum \subset P(X)$.
>   Then $\sum$ is a sigma ring on $X$ Iff (i) it is closed under countable union, (ii)$\forall A,B\in \sum, A-B\in \sum$.

If we start measure theory in this way, when we want to talk about a measure space, a set and a sigma-ring on this set should be given together. This is the only disadvantage of sigma ring in my opinion.

Let $M=\bigcup \sum$.

Then, $\sum$ is a sigma algebra on $M$ iff $M\in \sum$.

Thus, the definition of sigma ring is strictly stronger than that of sigma algebra.

I cannot understand why mathematicians got rid of this generalized definition and prefer a weaker one.

I remember that someone answered me that a lot of interesting spaces are integrable themselves. Which means, lot of interesting $\sigma$-*whatsoever* contains the whole space, so they are $\sigma$-algebras.

But, isn't there any interesting $\sigma$-ring which is not $\sigma$-algebra?

I really hate to go back and define something again more generally so that i have to prove every single theorem depending on property of the older definition.

For example, i started analysis with Rudin-PMA and he defined *Topology* as topology induced by metric space in usual sense. It was painful to me to distinguish theorems which hold only in metric space and which hold in topological space, when i learned general-topology later.

It's hard to confirm myself why mathematicians prefer this weak definition taking this risk..

Comment: Related: [Why define measures on $\sigma$-rings?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/162810/856)

Comment: @Rahul I saw that post too,but answers there do not answer my question.

Comment: Any easy example of a $\sigma$-ring which is not a $\sigma$-algebra would be the collection of all countable subsets of an uncountable set. Another one would be the collection of all [meagre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set) subsets of some nonmeagre topological space. However, these are both examples of $\sigma$-rings $\Sigma \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ where $S \subset T \in \Sigma$ implies $S \in \Sigma$.

Comment: @Mike Is that space interesting in the context of measure theory?

Comment: @Mathems: Sorry, but I am not sure.

Comment: Replace `\sum` by `\Sigma`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is perhaps more a comment than an answer, but it's a bit long for a comment:

I think the difference between the two theories is too small to worry about.

Let me elaborate a bit on that. First, given a σ-ring $\mathcal{R}$ on a set $X$, if it is not already a σ-algebra you can create a σ-algebra $\mathcal{F}=\{A\cup(X\setminus B)\colon A,B\in\mathcal{R}\}$. And a measure on $\mathcal{R}$ can be extended to a measure on $\mathcal{F}$ by setting it to $\infty$ on $\mathcal{F}\setminus\mathcal{R}$.

Conversely, given a σ-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ with a measure on it, the σ-finite members of $\mathcal{F}$ will form a σ-ring.

We don't quite get a simple one-to-one correspondence between measures on σ-rings and measures on σ-fields in this way, but I submit that the above makes translating back and forth between the two theories quite easy, if not trivial. I would, of course, be intrigued to see a counterexample to this conjecture.

Comment: Just for the sake of having a simple example at hand: Let $X$ be set. For each different point $x \in X$,  $\mathcal{F}_x = \{ S \subset X : x \notin S\}$ is a different $\sigma$-ring on $X$. However, each of them generates the same $\sigma$-algebra. Namely, the powerset of $X$.

Comment: @Mike Indeed; this is the sort of example I had in mind when I wrote the last paragraph. However, when you add measures into the mix, this example comes out differently. A measure on $\mathcal{F}_x$ extends to one on $\mathscr{P}(X)$ for which $\{x\}$ is an infinite atom, and if we restrict this measure to the σ-finite sets, we're back in a sub-σ-ring of $\mathcal{F}_x$ again.

Comment: "*I would, of course, be intrigued to see a counterexample to this conjecture.*"

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Let $\mathcal R$ be the $\sigma$-ring generated by all compact subsets of $X$.
Let $\mathcal A$ be the $\sigma$-algebra defined as follows.
$M \in \mathcal A$ if and only if $M \cap K \in \mathcal R$ for all compact sets $K$.
How do you interpret the relation between $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal A$ by your conjecture?
Note that $\mathcal B\subset \mathcal A$, where $\mathcal B$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all  open subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 20):

Measure Theory using $\sigma$-rings will lead to more complex notion of measurable function, with some non-intuitive results.

Let $\Omega$ be a set and let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra. Let $f$ be a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. We say that $f$ is measurable if for every Borel set $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(B)\in \Sigma$.

Now, suppose that $\Sigma$ is a  $\sigma$-ring and we try to use the same definition. Then, since $\Omega=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$, either $\Sigma$ is a  $\sigma$-algebra or there will be no measurable function from $(\Omega,\Sigma)$.

So, when working with $\sigma$-rings, we need a slightly different definition (as we find in Halmos' book). We say that $f$ is measurable if for every Borel set $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $[f\neq 0]\cap f^{-1}(B)\in \Sigma$.

This second definition allows the existence of measurable functions even if $\Sigma$ is just a $\sigma$-ring and not a $\sigma$-algebra. However, it leads to a few non-intuitive results. For instance: assume $\Sigma$ is just a $\sigma$-ring and not a $\sigma$-algebra. Then any non-zero constant function is NOT mensurable. As a consequence, if $f$ is measurable, then it is easy to prove, for instance, that $f+1$ is NOT measurable.

So, the theory of measurable and integrable functions is more naturally developed by using $\sigma$-algebras, instead of just $\sigma$-rings.

Comment: This is a very nice answer.

Comment: More specific to understand